# Enrutamiento de Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, post, rutas

tengo un proyecto en laravel el cual quisiera entender.
Tengo un formulario:

```
 <form action="{{ route('payment.gateway') }}" method="post" class="form">@csrf
```

El problema es que esa ruta "payment.gateway" no existe en mis archivos de rutas. Quisiera entender como se genera esa ruta, y ver que controlador está relacionado a esa ruta.

Comment: y el proyecto quien te lo paso???